# How to register for maps.google intents?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, url-scheme

I want to register my app for all intents like: http://maps.google...

When I register my app in my manifest like this:

```
 <data android:scheme="http" />
```

I get ALL http intents. But I ONLY want http://maps.google intents.
I tried to register for different schemes but nothing worked.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
android:host="maps.google.com"
```

as a second attribute.